# org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest - Read pending prevented - what is the cause?

Tags: jetty

I am seeing the following warning:

`[qtp1117509763-28] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest - Read pending for org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$BlockingReadCallback@7c403c6f prevented AC.ReadCB@6a90731a{HttpConnection@6a90731a::DecryptedEndPoint@50c47feb{/127.0.0.1:50414<->/127.0.0.1:7000,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=0/30000}}`

I am not sure what is triggering this. I am seeing it when I kick off a `CompletableFuture.runAsync(myRunnable)` and immediately return without blocking - when I run it synchronously and block, I don't see this. I am trying to understand why it is showing this warning; I am running Jetty 9.4.25

Comment: Please upgrade and try again, there have been several updates to that behavior since 9.4.25.  (Try Jetty 9.4.38.v20210224)

Comment: Ah ok. I saw an email list message with someone complaining at 9.2 and they said update to 9.3 to fix it so I thought the version was fine. Will test and report back.